# How to rename JSON page attribute without having to write a full custom serializer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following controller returning a list of items from the database:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Page<Movies> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return this.service.getAll(pageable);
}
```

As expected, Spring Boot serializes it correctly:

```
{
    "content": [ ... ],
    "pageable": { ... },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "totalElements": 35,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 20,
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

However, I would like to rename one of these attributes. For example, I would like to use `items` instead of `content` as the key name.

In this case, since `Page` is from `org.springframework.data.domain`, I cannot use a Jackson annotation to rename the property.

I could write a custom serializer (something like [this](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2018/2018-06-10-pageimpl-json-serialization-with-spring-boot-2/)), but I just want to rename the attribute, so I do not want to write it from scratch.

What could be a better approach to handle this issue?

Comment: what about using your own page response and some mapper (e.g. [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/)) which will be able to map spring paging to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @bilak. However, the approach with mixins marked as the answer worked better. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Mix-ins for that. You need an interface or abstract class where to apply the changes intended to the unmodifiable class:

```
interface MixIn<T> {
    @JsonProperty("items")
    List<T> getContent(); // rename property
}
```

and then register the Mix-in:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Slice.class, MixIn.class);
```

or with Spring Boot:

```
@Bean 
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() { 
    return builder -> builder.mixIn(Slice.class, MixIn.class); 
}
```

`Slice` is the actual class where the `content` property lives.
It will produce something like:

```
{
   "last":true,
   "totalElements":1,
   "totalPages":1,
   "size":0,
   "number":0,
   "numberOfElements":1,
   "first":true,
   "sort":null,
   "items":[
      "listItem"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go!

Comment: Thanks @Franjavi ! It worked pretty well. I suggest adding the bean configuration to your response for future readers reference: something like `@Bean public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() { return builder -> builder.mixIn(Slice.class, PageMixIn.class); }` in a configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to extend `PageImpl` and adding `items` attribute. Then you would need to map `PageImpl` object to your custom object leaving `content` empty by moving the content to `items`.

Not really sure if this is better than writing a custom serializer but at least this is another approach.